# Set height on source of picture tag

Tags: html

When loading a page containing a picture tag, the text is jumping around as the images are loaded because the browser doesn't know how tall the images are. How can I specify an image height for each source?

Comment: There is no easy way—you will have to sniff out the image dimensions first, which means having the preload the images anyway. It sounds like you are using (1) large number of images or (2) images with very large file sizes.

Comment: I think its normal to have images load after text even if its only a brief delay.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 different ways to achieve this

- Using the HTML `img` height attribute. Manually check your image height and set it. (not recommended)
- Using the CSS `min-height` property on each breakpoint (a bit nicer)
- [Preload the images using javascript](http://www.createjs.com/preloadjs), then show an animated loader that would slideDown and fill the image height until it fades in. (needs more work but definitely the best solution for a clean rendering).

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by your `<img>` tag, you do not specify his height

Use `<img height="x" width="y" src="myimage">` instead. In this way, when image is not loaded, the blank container will fit final dimension from beginning

Comment: But I need a height for every source image. There are multiple sizes because its a picture tag.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using jQuery library to get all tags `<img />` and set attribute "height" and "width", programmatically.